# create new Thread, passing two parameters

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm trying to create a new thread passing two parameters, I have searched too many times but still no result.
Here is my method:

```
public void Add(int smallest, int biggest)
{
  for (int i = smallest; i < biggest+1; i++)
  {
    Thread.Sleep(500);
    result = result + i;
  }
}
```

And I want to do as below:

```
 static void Main()
    {
      int x=10;
      int y=100;
      // in this line appear error
      Thread t=new Thread(Add);
      t.start(x,y);
    }
```

Comment: Do you think it might be useful to know what the error was?

Comment: I'm trying to understand this problem, but if you help me explain it, I will understand this problem faster.

Comment: Whenever you post a question involving an error, please always post the exact error message and relevant part of the stack trace. Just saying "// in this line appear error" means that everyone else has to figure out what error you're likely getting. We can't see your screen.

Comment: Ok, I understanded, in the next post I will write clearly. thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do it that way. The `Thread.Start()` method doesn't include overloads supporting more than one parameter.

However, the general goal is easily solved using an anonymous method as your thread body:

```
static void Main()
{
    int x=10;
    int y=100;
    // in this line appear error
    Thread t=new Thread(() => Add(x, y));
    t.start();
}
```

I.e. instead of your `Add()` method being the thread entry point, you wrap it in an anonymous method (declared here via the lambda expression syntax). The arguments `x` and `y` are "captured" by the anonymous method, to be passed into the `Add()` method when the thread starts.

One very important caution: the values from the variables are only retrieved *when the `Add()` method is actually called*. That is when the thread starts. If you modify their values before that happens, the new values are what are used.

This idiom is usable in any context where you want to pass strongly-typed and/or multiple arguments to a method where normally the API would allow none or some fixed number (like just one). Event handlers, `Task` entry points, I/O callbacks, etc. all can benefit from this approach.

Comment: Thank you so much. your answer matched my problem completly.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ThreadObj
{
public int smallest {get;set;}
public int biggest {get;set;}
}

public void Add(object obj)
{
ThreadObj myObj = (ThreadObj)obj;
  for (int i = myObj.smallest; i < myObj.biggest+1; i++)
  {
    Thread.Sleep(500);
    result = result + i;
  }
}

static void Main()
    {
      Thread t=new Thread(Add);
      t.start(new ThreadObj(){ smallest = 10, biggest = 100});
    }
```

Thread method only accept object as parameter. So you have to create object and pass value as object into that thread.

Comment: Your post is very helful, too. Thank you!